# Return a value based on initial string search

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to extract a ReportId based on the ResolvingId provided. So for example below if the ResolvingId is "ABC1234" then the ReportingId returned will be "98d2d1291671"

```
row.add('ID', 'Person.Id.[somecorp.com]Resolving.id', 'ABC1234', 'ABC1234');
row.add('Name', '', 'Smith, John', 'Smith, John');
row.add('Location', '', 'Asomewhere', 'Asomewhere');
row.add('documentIdentifier', '[somecorp.com]Report.Id.ReportId', '98d2d1291671', '98d2d1291671');
row.add('documentRepository', '[somecorp.com]Report.Id.ReportRepository', 'Something', 'Something');
row.add('ID', 'Person.Id.[somecorp.com]Resolving.id', 'CDE1234', 'CDE1234');
row.add('Name', '', 'Doe, Jane', 'Doe, Jane');
row.add('Location', '', 'Asomewhere', 'Asomewhere');
row.add('documentIdentifier', '[somecorp.com]Report.Id.ReportId', '23d2d1232571', '23d2d1232571');
row.add('documentRepository', '[somecorp.com]Report.Id.ReportRepository', 'Something', 'Something');
```

With my limited regex knowledge all I can return are all the ReportIds based on this:

```
ReportId', '(.*?)'
```

Is it possible to do this via regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use regex for this. If all the lines you're showing above are part of one giant string, you can create a simple function:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String getReportIdFromResolving(String searchText, String resolvingId) {

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Resolving\\.id.*" + resolvingId + 
    "[\\s\\S]*?ReportId', '(.*?)'");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(searchText);

  if (matcher.find()) {
    return matcher.group(1);
  }

  return null;

}

String origText = "..." // your text
System.out.println(getReportIdFromResolving(origText, "ABC1234"));

// 98d2d1291671
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lgy0hz/3)

Comment: Genius! Thanks very much